# getBlob() crashes if blob is over 2MB, substr method does not work

Tags: java, android, cursor

I am trying to use the getBlob method to retrieve a picture into a byte[].

However, if the the blob is over 2MB I noticed it will crash.

I found an article stating to use the substr function to get it in segments but this is not working.

Heres my sample, it's quite rough.

```
                      if( size > 2000000 ) {
                        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT substr(PICTURE, 1, 1000000)  FROM PICS WHERE ID = 1, null);
                        if( c.moveToFirst() ) {
                            byte[] image1, image2, image3, image4, image5;
                            image2 = c.getBlob(0);
                            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT substr(PICTURE, 1000001, 2000000)  FROM PICS WHERE ID = 1, null);
                            if( c.moveToFirst() ) {
                                image3 = c.getBlob(0);
                                image4 = concatenateByteArrays(image2, image3);
                                c = db.rawQuery("SELECT substr(PICTURE, 2000001, 3000000) FROM PICS WHERE ID = 1, null);
                                if( c.moveToFirst() ) {
                                    image5 = c.getBlob(0);
                                    image1 = concatenateByteArrays(image4, image5);
                                    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image1);
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Any help regarding this would be appreicated.

Thanks.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't recommend putting that kind of data in the db.  Large blobs of binary data that won't be relationally queried is not the strength of a database.  I'd put it on the filesystem, and the path to the file in the db.

Comment: Well, I want it like this so it is totally self contained. I am not trying to read 2GB of data, and it's definitely not sensitive if lost.

Answer (score 1):

this is good example show how to read data from blob column

Class.forName("YOUR_DB_DRIER");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

```
String sql = "SELECT name, description, image FROM pictures ";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
  String name = resultSet.getString(1);
  String description = resultSet.getString(2);
  File image = new File("D:\\java.gif");
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[512]; // as much as you increase this array  
             //   it will increase the performance of you data reading. 
  InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(3);
  while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer);
  }
  fos.close();
}
```